# how to say a "water area" in English?

Tags: word-request, nouns

> Swimming is an inexpensive sport as you don’t have to buy any tools
>   and it'd be even cheaper than any other kind of sport if you lived
>   nearby waters \ water area.

**I am not sure what is the right noun to describe living beside a (lake or beach or river)? I found some newspapers using "waters" or "water area" but not in this way**

Comment: It's natural to simply say "to live by/near water" to indicate proximity to a river, lake, sea or ocean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Bodies of water**" is the collective term that includes oceans, seas, lakes, and possibly smaller pools of water too, such as ponds or wetlands. However, it might be considered a little formal by some for your context.

From a non-language point of view though, not *all* bodies of water are suitable for wild swimming. I have taken a cursory look at a couple of websites about outdoor swimming and I couldn't see them using any collective terms. Swimming in lakes is different to swimming in the sea or ocean. The potential problem with using a collective term is that you might be suggesting that one can swim in *any* sea or lake, ignoring any potential dangers! I live by the sea and the coastguard routinely pull people out of the water who were in trouble.

For the above reason, I would personally clarify by saying:

> Swimming is an inexpensive sport as you don’t have to buy any tools, and it'd be even cheaper than any other kind of sport if you lived near *a body of water suitable for outdoor swimming*.

Some links that may be useful for further research into the correct terminology:

https://www.outdoorswimmingsociety.com/

http://www.wildswimming.co.uk

Comment: I'd shorten that to '...lived near a suitable body of water' and context will clarify what suitable refers to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Body of water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_of_water)

> Swimming is an inexpensive sport as you don’t have to buy any tools and it'd be even cheaper than any other kind of sport if you lived *near a **body of water***